# how to get X and Y coordinates of a text created using drawText()?

Tags: android, textview

I am newbie android developer I face this problem of getting XY coordinates of created text using drawText()inside custom TextView.i searched a lot but i didn't find any solution for my exact problem ,it tried with calculating X and Y using getTextBounds() and getFontMetrics but no luck.need some help,thanks.